# Push notifications suddenly stopped working in production

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

My company's app is already in the app store. The push notifications were working fine but suddenly it stopped working. I am new to the company, they told me to fix the issue. I went to their apple account portal. The production SSL certificate for push notification is not expired. But the distribution provisioning profile was inactive. I made it active by using edit button. But is there anything to do with the inactive distribution profile? I am wondering I have to release again? Please help me fixing the push notification issue. Please note the push notifications were working already.

Comment: You don't need to release a new build. May be you can create new set of `.pem` files that might be invalid and update in the server, but that would require the CSR file to do it, though you can create the CSR file using the private key of the certificate you have check step2 [here](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO13985)

Comment: I already replaced old .pem file with the new one using the existing SSL certificate. But still not receiving push notifications?

Comment: Well have you created dev and prod .pem both? and checking with dev provisioning profile and pitching sandbox to send notifications? it looks like you are checking the app with your Developer Provisioning profile then make sure you are calling sandbox from server it should work.

Comment: @user3391448:  What did you to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i faced the same issue and i created new certificate, profile & .pem file and give update to Appstore my app was updated on store but notification was not working in some devices.
Then from my superior i came to know that i have to create only new .pem file and replaced old .pem file by new one.

So you have don't need to update app just update .pem file only and replace by old .pem file.

Comment: I replaced old .pem file with the new one created using the existing SSL certificate. Still no use.

Comment: have you create .pem file using new certificate?

Comment: No I didn't create a new certificate since the existing one is not expired. Do I still want to create a new SSL certificate for creating .pem file?

Comment: As i have confirmed with my superior, it might be some other issue.
if provisioning profile invalid then its not effected on live app. if certificate expired then only issue will raise.